# if/then conditional statements using ints

Tags: integer, if-statement, conditional-statements, android

Super easy, I am sure - but in conditional if/then statements using droid, how do I go about using them with integers, ie:

```
int currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

public void getResult(int currentHour, Intent intent) {
    if (currentHour < 14) then:
        //do something
}
```

I know this isn't the right way to do it, but I am having a brain fart as to comparing ints...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void getResult(int currentHour, Intent intent) {

  if (currentHour < 14){
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect you're looking for

```
if (currentHour < 14) { 
    // do something
}
```

This is common to virtually all C-syntax languages.